# How to translate a native android sdk's usage instructions to Nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

We're having a hard time taking the first step in using a native library in NativeScript.

It's a Map library so I assume it has something to do with registering a new custom UI, but what gets me is the weird xml syntax.

The follow screenshots are from this page : https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/guide/develop-your-first-map-app.htm

Native instructions are for Android Studio :

[image]

The dependencies (Gradle) :

[image]

It also has a weird dependency for Java 8 features :

[image]

And lastly, the basic usage, which seems to require lots of platform specific native events :

[image]
[image]

For now we're only interested in an Android Proof of Concept, but eventually make and release a multi-platform plugin.

I know it's a lot of instructions and things asked for just one question, but here are our main confusions :

**1)** How to add the custom element to a NativeScript xml? Do we just set up the gradle imports and just add the following element directly? Also i'm assuming the `android:id` is unnecessary and we can just use `id`

```
<com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView
  android:id="@+id/mapView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView>
```

**2)** How to access the above element by its ID via Javascript? More specifically how to get it using VUE? Native Example :

```
import com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView;
MapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
ArcGISMap map = new ArcGISMap(Basemap.Type.TOPOGRAPHIC, 34.056295, -117.195800, 16); 
mMapView.setMap(map);
```

**3)** Are there any other steps we need to take into consideration? Specially considering we intend into making this into a full plugin eventually. Or is this more straightforward/simple than I'm making it?

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the XML example from the SDK docs, that is specific to Android's XML markup.

You have to create a new class (let's call it `MapView`), extending the base class `View` (from `tns-core-modules/ui/core/view`), in the `createNativeView` callback return instance of `com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView`. That's should be it, now you can register the `MapView` class and use it in your Vue template.

**Useful docs:**

- [Building Plugins](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/ui-plugin-custom#platform-specific-code)
- [Marshalling Java to JS](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js)

Comment: I understand that's the instructions for creating a custom UI plugin, but how to use it without creating a plugin initially? Could you post an example?

Comment: If you are not planning on creating a Plugin, then use [Placeholder](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/placeholder).

Comment: do you happen to know how to use Placeholder with Vue?

Comment: It should be just the same except the syntax will be how you would call an event in Vue. [Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=VtljXK&v=2) is working sample.